# How to find docker containers can talk each other

Tags: docker

I have created these 4 docker containers connected to webapp network

1. App container
2. Sales container
3. Admin container
4. Support container

Is there any way to identify these containers can talk each other ?

Comment: Can you add some more details? How are you hosting the containers? How did you create the container images?

Comment: `ping` can be used here

Answer (score 2):

Try this command in your cli

```
docker container exec -it App ping Sales
```

Here you can check your App and Sales container can talk each other, Similar way you can check for other containers